# Pull from remote failed: path too long (Windows)

Tags: git

While pulling from a remote, I get an error about file path too long. This is apparently only an issue in Windows, as I have discovered over time.

This question is more for a coworker than for me - my local is working fine. Every time he tries to pull he gets the same errors about the same pathologically long file names, which seem to have been fixed a while ago but he still has the error.

I had a thought that adding those literal file names that fail to the project '.gitignore'.. any other thoughts on a workaround?

Comment: which git version do you use? I remember they were fixing some longpath issues. Try setting `core.longpaths`

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue before, so you've two options, the first is to update your repo to make the path shorter, the second one is to move your repo to lower folder for example **C:\**. 
The second works for me because the repo was cloned in a very deep folder then it solve my issue but I'm not sure if it will helps in your case.